# How to make "too much load" messages

Tags: performance

I see these kinds of messages on twitter and other places.... how do they work?  Is it MySQL connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be shown if the database refused a connection or if the system load (read from /proc/loadavg) is too high. It could also be shown if too many users are logged in - but that's only likely for web applications where logged in users are expensive.. certain games for example where lots of state information must be kept while someone is logged in.

Answer (score 1):

You can measure response time of each request (or a given fraction of the requests). If the response time goes up above a threshold you start rejecting requests.

If you measure SQL connection etc you need to know where your bottle necks are at a given moment. If your application is limited by bandwidth between your servers or something else counting SQL connections will not help you.